# How to use __func__ in 8051

Tags: c, keil, 8051

I'm trying to print functions name with `__func__` macro in a 8051 project.
But when I build on Keil, It has an error like this:

```
main.c(50): error C202: '__func__': undefined identifier
```

have any macro others similary?
Please help me solves it.

Comment: `__func__` is a C99 feature so it depends on the compiler to support that. It has nothing to do with 8051

Comment: 8051 is 1980s technology. Compilers designed for it aren't likely up to date with standard C. Consider switching to a MCU core which isn't 40 years old and mostly obsolete.

Comment: @Lundin there's the open sourced [SDCC](http://sdcc.sourceforge.net/) which supports C99 and compiles code for 8051. In fact there are far older MCUs/CPUs with an active community out there like Z80

Comment: @phuclv One needs to separate archaeology and retrocomputing for the sake of nostalgia from professional product development in the year 2021 though. Obviously there's nothing wrong with playing around with 8051 and Z80 in a hobbyist retrocomputing setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_pp_predefmacroconst.htm) says, the Keil C51 compiler does not support this macro, and apparently no other of similar functionality:

> The Cx51 Compiler provides the following predefined constants you may use in preprocessor directives and C code to create portable programs.
>
> | Constant | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | `__C51__` | Version number of the compiler (for example, 701 for version 7.01). |
> | `__CX51__` | Version number of the compiler (for example, 701 for version 7.01). |
> | `__DATE__` | Date when the compilation was started in ANSI format (month dd yyyy). |
> | `__DATE2__` | Date when the compilation was started in short form (mm/dd/yy). |
> | `__FILE__` | Name of the file being compiled. |
> | `__LINE__` | Current line number in the file being compiled. |
> | `__MODEL__` | Memory model selected: 0 for SMALL, 1 for COMPACT, 2 for LARGE. |
> | `__TIME__` | Time when the compilation was started. (Format: hh:mm:ss) |
> | `__STDC__` | Defined to 1 to indicate full conformance with the ANSI C Standard. |